# Load a certain partial view depending on URL parameter using mvc3 and jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to have one view called Example and have the ability to update and load different partial views into one html div tag.  In the case below I would like the page to display a details partial if the URL parameter is an id or a grid of results if the URL parameter is search.

Optional URL parameters:
..../Example?id=1234
..../Example?search=ccc

User would pass in one of the above and either _details.cshtml or _grid.cshtml would update the details div below.

Div tag in Example.cshtml

```
<div id="Details"></div>
```

I'm just stuck on where this partial view filtering would take place, jquery or in the controller?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller should pass a view model to the view. This view model could the partial to be loaded:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string DetailsPartial { get; set; }
}
```

and then based on the presence of the id or search parameters the controller will populate this property:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id, string search)
{
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        DetailsPartial = (id != null) ? "_details" : "_grid"
    }; 
    return View(model);
}
```

and in the corresponding view:

```
@model MyViewModel
...
<div id="Details">
    @Html.Partial(Model.DetailsPartial)
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, let me try that out.